# CSS/JS not loading - Permissions error?

Tags: javascript, css, cache, permissions

I seem to have had a permissions error in var and specifically `var/cache`.

Both were previously set to **755**, which has not caused issues before. This morning my CSV files stopped being generated by cron to the `var/export_bkp` directory, I resolved this by setting permissions to **777**.

I'm now having the problem that my site has dropped the stylesheets. I tried changing permissions of `media/js` **&** `media/css` to **777**, and I can see it is caching stylesheets in there correctly, however, they are not being displayed on the front end.

I have tried flushing cache via Magento admin but still, have nothing.
Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Check ownership for pub/static and media folder

Comment: i think you shouldn't change to 777, keep 755 and check ownership for pub/static and check file js, css exist

Answer (score 0):

**If you are facing problem of css and js page load design after installation in magento2
please follow the following step-:
open the terminal and navigate to magento web root**

$ cd /var/www/html/magento2

Step 1.

```
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Step 2.

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Step 3.

```
make sure apache “rewrite_module” is enable and then restart the server
```

Step 4.

```
$ chown -R www-data&colon;www-data /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 5.

```
$ chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
```

Step 6.

delete cache folder under var/cache

The above step working. I hope this will work for you also.

Comment: check .htaccess file inside the pub folder...

Comment: Every time one uses `chmod -R 777` kittens die.

Comment: Then magento devs kill more kittens then there are stars in milky way..

Comment: Lol, just saw it, @NACHIMUTHU RAMALINGAM you should not just 'chmod -R 777' the whole magento instance man, only needed folders like pub/static, generated, var etc .